# How to return the max value of one column, depending of 2 other variables in 2 columns

Tags: excel

How can I get the cumulative amount (all charges per supplier) per supplier per month, final, which takes into account just the highest version of the statement?

[image]

For example, for `Ann` and `June 13` the value will be 30 (first statement will be ignored and the value will be evaluated after all 2 criteria are met).

I found an answer based one one criteria (see below) but how to do it based on 2 or more criteria.

```
=MAX((A1:A5="car2")*B1:B5) //(if we have in B1:b5 the highest value required abd in A1:a5-one criteria
```

Comment: for a simple max given two criteria you can use `=MAX(IF(A1:A10="x",IF(B1:B10="y",C1:C10)))` but you expect 30 here? so it's not a simple max given 2 criteria is it?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added an additional column as per your formula and then used sumproduct  =SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$8=$A$2:$A$8)*($B$2:$B$8=$G3)*($C$2:$C$8=H$2)*($E$2:$E$8)) //if F is the column that calculates the highest statement version per given criterias, B is supply month,C is supplier, E is value. Do you think that can be used any other formulas (apart from sumproduct, as sumproduct takes much memory and in one huge spreadsheet I prefer to use other formulas.

Comment: For further clarification of the above formula G3 is June-13, H2 is Ann and the result is 30. Any more suggestions that take less memory would be much appreciated..